Zod schema with nested defaults
I'm using Zod in my TypeScript project to create a default options object for a function. The default object looks like this:
const defaultOptions = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: {
      c1: 3,
      c2: 4,
      c3: {
         x: 1,
         y: 2,
         z: 3
      }
   }
};

When calling the function, you can provide an object that overrides any of the default values. If you pass an empty object {}, the function should use the defaults for all keys. The function signature might look something like this:
function myFunction(options: Partial<typeof defaultOptions> = {}) {
  const finalOptions = { ...defaultOptions, ...options };
  // Function logic here
}

In Zod, I want to define a schema where each key is optional, but if a key is not provided, its default value from the nested defaultOptions object should be used. For example:
const schema = z.object({
  a: z.number().optional().default(1),
  b: z.number().optional().default(2),
  c: z.object({
    c1: z.number().optional().default(3),
    c2: z.number().optional().default(4),
    c3: z.object({
      x: z.number().optional().default(1),
      y: z.number().optional().default(2),
      z: z.number().optional().default(3)
    }).optional().default(/*...*/)
  }).optional().default(/*...*/)
});

The issue I'm facing is that with this approach, I have to redundantly specify defaults at multiple levels of the nested structure. If I have deeply nested objects, each default value must be repeated multiple times once in each nesting level, making the schema definition cumbersome and error-prone.
Is there a better way to handle deeply nested defaults with Zod, so that I don't have to specify each nested default multiple times?
Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

!!!! BEWARE !!!! Your spread operator isn't going to work correctly with nested object. The spread only merges the first layer, and does not do a deep merge. I believe that the lodash library has a utility for that. Check online. Anyway, I personally always find that I have to write some custom code or wrappers around anything I do with zod. And that's ok. zod is very opinionated and if there is something it doesn't do easily, its okay to write custom code to enhance it

What exactly are you passing for /*...*/?
